# 'net' refuses to emit 'close' event in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

hi I have the following code:

```
this.stop = function() {
    this.server.close();
    var thisServer = this;
    this.server.on('close',function() {
        thisServer.emit('stop');        
    });     
};
```

after using the server and calling the stop function, the server refuses
to emit 'close' event and

```
    this.server.on('close',function() {
        thisServer.emit('stop');        
    });
```

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.server.on('close',function() {
    thisServer.emit('stop');        
});    
this.server.close();
var thisServer = this;
```

Bind the close event before you invoke close.

Alternatively try `this.server.destroy();`